# Geolocation and database schema

Tags: database, geolocation

I am building an application that stores the following: People, Places and Posts.

People can create Posts and live in a Place, and Posts also belong to a Place.

Users of the application when viewing posts will be able to see the location of the post that was made, e.g. London, UK. They will then be able to click on that place and see a list of other posts that are also posted in that location.

On the home page of the application I want to show a map that using geolocation will get the current users location and then show an overlay of bubbles of posts that have been posted near them that they can then click on to view that post.

e.g.

[image]

That all being said I'm trying to figure out the best way to build the database. This is the schema I have in my head so far:

```
**Posts**
id
title
datetime
content
author_id

**People**
id
firstname
lastname

**Places**
id
name
lon
lat
```

As you can see their is a relationship between the Posts and People with the user_id foreign key, but I also need to build a relationship between the Places and Posts and People, but I don't want data to get repeated, e.g. have London stored twice in the DB.

I have thought about doing a linker table but that could get messy as the id of a person and a post may be the same so I'd need some sort of additional id to tell them apart.

Can anyone offer any suggestions/best practices for building such an app?

Should I be even saving all this data in the places table as it would take a while to build up the locations so not sure how people like: http://www.touristeye.com/London-p-1066

Thanks

Comment: How about just add a reference to places on both people and posts? As i read it you want a many-to-one relation from posts to places and post to people? Note, just for consistency then keep the naming to present!

Comment: For a second comment - because you want to search for other things near a location i think you should look into spatial databases, becuase they are optimzed for that kind of data.

Comment: A location may have more than one post and person so it's a many to may relationship!

Comment: But can a person and post have more than one place?

Comment: @Cameron, but a post can only have 1 (original) author and a person can only be in one location, so if you put `places.id` in `people` then you have your link.

Comment: @Ben so are you saying I only need to link the People and Places as the Post will then pull the location from the Person table? Because the issue there is a person may live in London but make a post in say Manchester hence need a reference in both tables.

Comment: I'm saying that's what I'd do :-). As @aweis said, there's no harm putting `places.id` in `posts` as well, if you already have the information. It'd make searching a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your Places table is not quite right.  For example, it suggests that a place such as New York would have a unique lat/long -- which is perfectly a sensible way to analyse the data for some applications but possibly not for yours. I'd suggest making lat and long attributes of Posts and model the relationship between Places and Posts some other way.  I'd then modify Places to hold the attributes necessary to record some idea of the area that a Place occupies -- perhaps a simple polygon, perhaps something more complex.

If you are happy with a simple idea of Place, ie that every lat/long tuple is in only one Place (eg London) and that there is no interesting relationship between Places (eg Westminster is inside London) then you could model the relationship between Places and Posts by a foreign key.  But this would mean that all Posts within a Place were given the same lat/long tuple, which may not be what you want at all.

At a guess, you probably don't intend to (or need to) implement anything approaching a spatial database so don't let the re-modelling of Places get out of hand.

**EDIT** after comment

It's too simple to think 'duplication of data is a bad thing'.  For one, I don't think that you are duplicating data, for another there are reasons why you (or anyone else designing a database) might want to.  Broadly speaking, those reasons relate to query performance.  But turning to your issue:

I think that the location from which a post is made is not the same thing as a Place.  From what you have written you want to, for example, record the lat/long of posts made 100ft apart but tie them to the same place (I'm guessing that Times Square is more than 100ft across).  If you have a simple concept of Place you could implement the relationship by using a foreign key.  But the definition of Place, in terms of lat/long, is independent of the locations of Posts made from within it.  If you forced all posts made in Times Sq to have the same lat/long you would be losing information abut their precise location.

And losing information is another of those bad things that we are not supposed to do with databases (unless, of course, there is a good reason for it).

Comment: Well I want to show their location on a map so I would need fairly accurate data e.g. Times Square, NY, USA. However if I'm just storing the long and lat for a post in the posts table itself how would I link it back to the places table unless I also create the data there as well? But then how I do stop duplication...

Comment: Could you post what you think the DB Schema should be whereby a post records the long/lat and a user could click a link on that post that would show where other posts have been made in that area...

Comment: 'Click a link' is pure UI; any impact that the UI has on the DB design depend on the UI design, I haven't a clue what you plan in that aspect so, no I can't help there.  I can't help further either on the design of your Places data structures as I don't think your requirements are clear.  Finally, I wouldn't be designing this DB from a blank sheet of paper, I'd be using an existing geo-enabled DB.  If you need more assistance, look at some of the documentation for those (both MySQL and PostGRES have spatial extensions and are well-documented on-line).

Comment: See my OP for an example of a link a user might click on to view the location and then see other posts at the location e.g. `/places/Huddersfield-102`